# How to get rid of duplicates from specified index and creae a single list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, list, data-structures

My input list is:

```
data = [['A','0'],['B','0'],['C','1'],['D','2'],['E','0'],['F','4'],['G','9'],['H','1'],['I','4'],]
```

and expecting output is:

```
data = [['A','B','E','0'],['C','H','1'],['D','2'],['F','I','4']]
```

in java script.
My hair is gone while thinking for solution.

Comment: The expecting output does not make any sense. You have to explain what exactly has to happen to get to that output from that input. As it is with the explanation you gave it does not make any sense.

Comment: from what i see, its grouped by the number in second index, only thing confusing is [G,9] is missing

Comment: Sorry... My mistake... [G,9] should have been there

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the letter values in an object with the digits as keys; then use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key/value pairs and finally [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to add the digits to the array of letter values:

```js
const data = [
  ['A', '0'],
  ['B', '0'],
  ['C', '1'],
  ['D', '2'],
  ['E', '0'],
  ['F', '4'],
  ['G', '9'],
  ['H', '1'],
  ['I', '4']
];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (!c[v[1]]) c[v[1]] = [];
  c[v[1]].push(v[0]);
  return c;
}, {})).map(([k, v]) => [...v, k]);
console.log(result);
```